# Rounding a float number in python

Tags: python, numbers, rounding

I have a float numer

> a = 1.263597

I hope get

> b = 1.2635

But when I try

> round (a,4)

then result is

> 1.2636

What should I do?

Comment: Why are you expecting "1.2635" when the normal rounding rules should get you "1.2636", since there's a "9" after the "5"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `math.floor` with this small modification -

```
import math

def floor_rounded(n,d):
    return math.floor(n*10**d)/10**d

n = 1.263597
d = 4

output = floor_rounded(n,d)
print(output)
```

```
1.2635
```

For your example, you can just do `math.floor(1.263597 * 10000)/10000`

---

**EDIT:** Based on the valid comment by @Mark, here is another way of solving this, but this time forcing the custom rounding using string operations.

```
#EDIT: Alternate approach, based on the comment by Mark Dickinson

def string_rounded(n,d):
    i,j = str(n).split('.')
    return float(i+'.'+j[:d])

n = 8.04
d = 2

output = string_rounded(n,d)
output
```

```
8.04
```

Comment: Beware corner cases arising from the What You See Is Not What You Get nature of binary floating-point. E.g., `floor_rounded(8.04, 2)` gives `8.03` on my machine (and `floor_rounded(8.03, 2)` gives `8.02`, so the rounding operation isn't even idempotent).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Completely agree with your point above, have added a method using string manipulations which should avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

Plain Python without importing any libraries (even not standard libraries):

```py
def round_down(number, ndigits=None):
    if ndigits is None or ndigits == 0:
        # Return an integer if ndigits is 0
        return int(number)
    else:
        return int(number * 10**ndigits) / 10**ndigits

a = 1.263597
b = round_down(a, 4)
print(b)
```

```py
1.2635
```

Note that this function rounds towards zero, i.e. it rounds down positive floats and rounds up negative floats.

Answer (score 0):

```
def round_down(number, ndigits=0):
    return round(number-0.5/pow(10, ndigits), ndigits)
```

Run:

```
round_down(1.263597, 4)
>> 1.2635
```

Comment: That's not a good idea. Rounding down, which seems to be what the OP wants, is not the same as rounding a smaller number.

Comment: Right, but there is a trick of adding/subtracting 0.5 to any number when wanting to round up/down that is useful for a fraction of half too